# Twilio SIP Trunk CallerID w/ FreePBX

Tags: twilio, asterisk, freepbx

I'm using Twilio for my SIP Trunks with Asterisk/FreePBX. There's no caller id info coming through on incoming calls. Is there something I have to enable within twilio console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - My CallerID wasn't working because I was receiving the country code "+1" along with the 10 digit phone number on incoming calls. I installed the "Set CallerID" module and set "${CALLERID(num):2}" for the CallerID Number to strip the first two characters from the callerId number field. I'm using CID Superfecta on my install and also found I had to remove my "CallerID Lookup" module, and then on the incoming route, enable CID Superfecta. Good Luck